# Change Contact Roles Dialog?

Tags: contact, opportunitycontactrole

The dialog for the selection of contact roles differs in account & case from contact roles dialog of opportunities.

In account & case objects I can only select one contact and have to click "Save & New" for the next.

[image: Opportunities]

[image: Account]

In opportunity object I have a list of input fields for up to four contacts.
Users in our company prefer opportunities input method. So, my questions are:

1. Is it possible to add multiple fields/contacts to the contact roles dialog of account & case objects (so that users can save multiple contacts with one "Save")?
2. How can I define/change the number of fields/contacts in opportunities contact roles dialog (and maybe in account & case)?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll notice that your Account Contact Role (ACR) dialogue has 3 fields:

- Contact
- Role
- isPrimary

There's also a button below marked "Save and New". You can have more than one ACR, but you can only have one that's primary. You also need to define the various `Roles` these contacts have for an Account. All you're seeing is a difference in the way they're displayed and entered into your Account Page.

It's important to note that on Opportunity, you should only have one contact that's primary. If you have more than one, it can create issues for you that can be troublesome to diagnose. This is in reference to the primary decision maker for the opportunity. That's the only role where `isPrimary` really matters.

All of these are configured by going to `Customize > sObject > Contact Roles on sObjects` where sObject = Account, Case or Opportunity.

To change these dialogues, you'd essentially need to recreate your page layouts and replace them with custom code.